# Global tags or key-value on Sentry/Raven using log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, sentry, raven

I'm using Sentry/Raven with log4j2 on an internal desktop application.

Using the app, when the user logs in, I'd like to register in a context the username so, when the app crash, I know who in the company was using the app and I can inquire with him.

The app uses several threads, and a crash may happen, of course, in any of them.
The raven-java-log4j2 documentation states that we should use `ThreadContext.put("username", username)` but that only works if the crash happens later **in the same thread**.

How can I set this `"username"` key-value in a "global context" so that the information is transmitted to sentry no matter the thread ?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find an answer for this one?

Comment: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger logger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) LogManager.getRootLogger();
SentryAppender appender = (SentryAppender) logger.context.configuration.appenders["Sentry"];
appender.setTags("username:" + username);   
Not sure yet if it works with already created loggers...